# Suggestions on what tools to use with MERN stack

Tags: frameworks, mern

summer break is coming up soon and I want to work on a couple of personal projects to practice my coding skills and learn/experiment with new tools and frameworks.

I am planning on working on a personal stock exchange database/website for my first project where I'll store and keep track of stocks and whatever information I want (whether custom or retrieved through APIs) accessible online. I don't know React but I am familiar with the rest of the MERN stack.

My question is what tools/software/(anything else that you think is cool or current) can I use to make it as close to a real-life company software as I can? My goal is to be able to showcase my experience later on when I graduate college and also to have fun with something new.

Edit: An example of something extra I'm looking for could be a service that allows me to collect user data on my website to see how popular it is (I can add functionality to allow people to create accounts for their own profile)

Bonus: If you have any good tutorials or sources that you can recommend me to learn what you would suggest, that would be awesome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use "MongoDB Compass" for checking db, "Postman" for testing API, VS code with React Snippets and linters(probably other editors also have something similar) for coding and "react developer tools" chrome extension.

Regarding your project, I highly advice you to use socket.io for real time communication.

I also suggest Asana for project management.

These are the tools I use daily and they are widely used in the industry.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I’ll check them all out!